# tar joint between garage wall and asphalt

Tags: waterproofing, brick, cement, asphalt, sealant

There's a kind of a gap between the asphalt and the garage which causes moisture to accumulate there.

[image: Close up view of the gap between garage side wall and asphalt]

[image: View of the side wall]

I'd like to seal that gap by making a tar joint:

https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.sealant-asphalt-black-300ml.1000409856.html?autoSuggest=pip[

How should I proceed with this? Is it a complex job? Do I first need to clean the gap as much as possible? What do I need to watch out for? And so on.

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the asphalt-base (tar) crack filler would probably work, it is also sticky and messy and will probably end up being ugly against your stucco/plaster wall.

I recommend a self-leveling flexible urethane filler, often sold as "concrete crack filler".

Either way, you will need to sweep out that crack as well as you can, then blast it clean with a stream of water from a hose, then let it dry thoroughly. Take your time when applying so you get a clean, nice looking, even bead.

Comment: Didn't do it yet so I didn't mark your answer as done/accepted. I'll come back in a few weeks :)

Comment: I have a follow up question: what will happen if there's rain the day I put the Polyurethane self-leveling filler? Apparently there might be bubbles forming. Is that very bad? If it is, then maybe I can cover the seal with something for a day? (We get a lot of quick, spontaneous deluge type of showers in the spring, Completely unpredictable)